# How to identify rejected rows in ADF Copy?

Tags: azure-data-factory

How do you identify/capture rejected rows in ADF Copy activity?

SQL -> Snowflake, using Copy task some rows are rejected due to various issues like data time or escape char, etc. I see the error message is logged but could not identify which row is it really in from source table.

How did you handle it, if you have done it?

This is what I see being captured, but I like the actual row data to be redirected for further action.
**

---------- Timestamp,Level,OperationName,OperationItem,Message 2023-08-26 02:03:35.1352256,Warning,TabularRowSkip,"""""""tableA""""[""""$12"""":12]"",","file name azure://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/cstaging/ac3840b1-d220-43c2-bab8-ss/SnowflakeImportCopyCommand/data_ac3840b1-d220-43c2-bab8-d1f3b83c55ef_b2862424-160f-44c4-bd4a-0f1f53c287a1.txt, first error Found character 'T' instead of field delimiter ',', first error line 2, first error character 159"

**

I don't see a straight option available to apply

Answer (score 0):

You need to query the log file after setting the logging level properly, to the verbose level. Do not enable reliable logging. In the logs, the OperationItem column is where you have the file name or row number, but in case of rows, it might be cryptic to read. I see table and 12, so maybe 12. row.

Skipped row details should show up in the logs. If not can you show me how your log files look? This might be different in Snowflake case.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-fault-tolerance#supported-scenarios

Comment: I don't see the option where the actual rejected row is captured. I see the error message, etc. being logged; but I need the capability to redirect all faulty/rejected rows - so that I can take further action.

Comment: @Mahesh, can you share with me how your logs look? Also this is from the verbose level , right? You can update your question with example rows from your logs

Comment: Timestamp,Level,OperationName,OperationItem,Message
2023-08-26 02:03:35.1352256,Warning,TabularRowSkip,"""""""table""""[""""$12"""":12]"",","file name azure://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/cstaging/ac3840b1-d220-43c2-bab8-ss/SnowflakeImportCopyCommand/data_ac3840b1-d220-43c2-bab8-d1f3b83c55ef_b2862424-160f-44c4-bd4a-0f1f53c287a1.txt, first error Found character 'T' instead of field delimiter ',', first error line 2, first error character 159"

Comment: @Mahesh, I see I will look into this in a bit. But can you also add to additional snowflake copy options  "RETURN_FAILED_ONLY" property with value as "TRUE" according to snowflake documentation. This should be somewhere in the copy activity

Comment: Also note that there are 3 scenarios that are supported for logging the incompatible rows, in other scenarios this feature is not supported as documentation implies. But you can try this snowflake return failed only option and see if it helps. If its a supported scenario, its logged to an address like: 'https://[your-blob-account].blob.core.windows.net/[path-if-configured]/[copy-activity-run-id]/[auto-generated-GUID].csv' They are always .csv files.  OperationItem column is where you should look.